# How to specify update.chain programmatically in SOLR

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I would like to know how I can specify the update chain programmatically when performing the SolrQuery. 
I have defined the chain like this in solr config.xml
Thanks in advance

```
 <updateRequestProcessorChain name="productSearchChain" default="true">
   <processor class="com.mycompany.IdSuffixProcessorFactory">
     <str name="someParameter">Value</str>
   </processor>
   <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
 </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to provide the name of the chain in **update.chain** URL parameter. If you look at the schemaless examples, it just has the relevant update.chain in the defaults.

Comment: I wanted to know , how you would do it programmatically. SolrQuery.set("update.chain","valueofchain"); //should this be the way to go was the queston